# $F(E)$ is proper iff $E$ has the finite intersection property (Blackburn, 2.5.1(c))

Tags: logic, solution-verification, set-theory

> **Blackburn's Modal Logic, Ex 2.5.1 (c)**: Let $E\subseteq \mathcal P(W)$, the power set of $W$. Let $F = F(E)$ be the filter generated by $E$. Prove that $F$ is proper iff $E$ has the finite intersection property (FIP).

My work:

$[\Leftarrow]$: Suppose $E$ has the finite intersection property. Then the intersection of any finite number of elements of $E$ is non-empty. Suppose $\varnothing\in F$, i.e. $F$ is not proper. Then, **can we conclude** that $\varnothing\in E$ as well? If yes, then we have our contradiction - since the intersection of any finite number of sets with $\varnothing$ is $\varnothing$, violating FIP.

$[\Rightarrow]$: Suppose $F$ is proper. This is the same as saying $\varnothing\notin F$. This means $\varnothing\notin E$, because if it were, we'd be in trouble. I'm using that $$F = \bigcap \left\{X\subseteq \mathcal P(W): X \text{ is a filter}, E\subseteq X   \right\}$$
If FIP doesn't hold, then there exist a finite number of sets $Y_1,...,Y_n$, $Y_i \in E$ such that $\bigcap_i Y_i = \varnothing$. However, $Y_i\in E \implies Y_i \in F$. $F$ is a filter, and so is closed under finite intersections. We must have $\bigcap_i Y_i \in F$, but $\bigcap_i Y_i = \varnothing$ which is a contradiction since $F$ is proper and $\varnothing\notin F$.

I believe the second part is fine, but the first part isn't. Could someone check and help me refine this proof? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the implication $(\Leftarrow)$:

If $E$ has the finite intersection property, then any nonempty subset $A$ of $W$ which contains an intersection of a finite collection of elements of $E$ must be in $\mathcal{F}(E)$, because it is a filter. Actually, it can be easily checked that the collections of such $A$'s is a filter which contains $E$, and therefore we have

$$ \mathcal{F}(E)=\{A\in \mathcal{P}(W): \exists \text{ a finite collection }U_{1},\dots, U_{n}\in E\text{ such that } \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}U_{i}\subseteq A\}$$

From this, we deduce that $\mathcal{F}(E)$ is a proper filter

Comment: Hmm, could you add more details? I don't understand your proof. How did you deduce that $F(E)$ is proper?

Comment: By the way, I know this:
$$F(E) = \{X \in\mathcal P(W): X = W \text{ or } \exists Y_1,...,Y_n \in E, Y_1\cap Y_2\cap ... \cap Y_n \subseteq X\}$$
Does this help? I think you've used/proved this at some point, but I'm just not able to connect the dots.

Comment: If $\varnothing$ belongs to $F(E)$, then there exists a finite collection $U_{1},\dots, U_{n}$ of elements of $E$ such that $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}U_{i}\subseteq \varnothing$. But this is impossible, since $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}U_{i}\neq \varnothing$ (because $E$ has the finite intersection property.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense!